# I need to do a join where, but need to avoid repeating rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, distinct, where-clause

I have a scope

scope :with_tags, lambda {|tag|  joins(:tags).where('tags.name in ( ? )',tag )} #Questionnaire.with_tags(["Restaurants","Real State"])

Questionnaire.with_tags(["Restaurants","Real State"]).to_sql

=> "SELECT `questionnaires`.* FROM `questionnaires` INNER JOIN `quest_tags` ON `questionnaires`.`id` = `quest_tags`.`questionnaire_id` INNER JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `quest_tags`.`tag_id` WHERE (tags.name in ( 'Restaurants','Real State' ))"

what I need is
"SELECT **DISTINCT** `questionnaires`.* FROM `questionnaires` INNER JOIN `quest_tags` ON `questionnaires`.`id` = `quest_tags`.`questionnaire_id` INNER JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `quest_tags`.`tag_id` WHERE (tags.name in ( 'Restaurants','Real State' ))"

What do I need to do to my scope to get the **DISTINCT** in the select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scope :with_tags, lambda {|tag|  joins(:tags).where('tags.name in ( ? )',tag ).group('questionnaires.id')}